# UITableViewCell auto-height for iPad different from iPhone using iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

i'm dealing with a strange situation with a UITableView (inside an UIViewController, not an UITableViewController). My cells have a UILabel which font size depends if the app is running on iPhone or iPad (size will be bigger on iPad).

I already managed that using Size Classes and it works but there is a little problem. When the UITableView appears, the cell has the iPhone's height for just one moment, and then, it changes to the iPad's height.

How can I avoid that little transition?

**EDIT:** Just realized that it works fine using iOS 9

Comment: Where in your class have you added constraints?

Comment: I added all the constraint in the storyboard

Comment: My cells appear broken too. A second after they layout properly. I think this might be a bug.